# How to change a UITableView position using UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

How can I make a UITableView change by scrolling on the screen? I want the TableView to be on top of a map at the bottom and when the user scrolls from there the TableView will change its position to where the scroll was stopped.
I want to make something like the "Apple Control/Notification center" or like "Moovit" app (the TableView on the bottom)

Comment: u use a scrollview, put in tableview and a mapview below it?

Comment: Yes. But the scroll view scrolls the table view itself and not his position on the screen

Comment: well basically, u have to use code to implements that, when the mapview on top is visible, disable the tableview interaction, enable the scrollview one, when tableview is fullscreen (u scroll it up), then disable scroll view and enable the tableview, use bool value to indicate that

Comment: I want that the user will be able to swipe the tableview just until the half of the screen, so the map view is always visible, but my problem is when I put the scrollview as a subview to the table view it scrolls the tableview cells. How can I make it scroll the view?